# Change components' properties on event triggered

Tags: java, swing, components, panel

I have a panel with mupltiple components and other panels. Some components are functionally linked to another. So if I change one component's value some others react in a way. For this I made all of those components to object properties and added event listeners to them.

In my case I want to reset some properties of a linked component (like the text of a `JTextField`), so I change the properies' values of the object property but I can't see my changes after the event although my listener is called.

Repainting shouldn't be the problem. I'm calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on my whole frame after resetting the data - no changes.

I think I'm misunderstanding some kind of referencing of the component objects. Can you help me here?

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
private ItemSelecter isBase;
private ItemSelecter isSet;

public MyPanel() {
    isBase.addItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            ArrayList<String> data = getMyAwesomeData();
            isSet.setData(data);

            Meta.frame.revalidate();
            Meta.frame.repaint();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: @FastSnail I added it. I can't see the changed data after the event was triggered.

Comment: not enough...what is Meta ?

Comment: Meta is just a class for storing static session data. So that's not the problem. But I found it after a while now... The problem was in my ItemSelecter class. I didn't refresh the ActionListener in its button, so the data showing up by clicking it wasn't refreshed... >.> Thanks nevertheless!